# Exibir o maior e o menor valor entre dois inteiros quando forem diferentes entre si

Tags: c, if, else

Não estou conseguindo exibir os valores de menor e maior.

> Faça um algoritmo que leia dois números e indique se são iguais ou, se diferentes, mostre o maior e o menor nesta sequência.

```
int V1,V2;

printf("Valor 1 :"); scanf("%d",&V1);
printf("Valor 2 :"); scanf("%d",&V2);

if (V1==V2){
    printf("O valor é igual \n\n ");
}
else{
    printf("O valor é diferente \n\n");
}
if (V1>V2){
    printf("O valor maior é %d",V1);
}
if (V1<V2){
    printf("O valor menor é %d", V2);
}
return(0);
system("pause");
```

Comment: No ultimo `if` tem que mostrar o `V1` e não `V2`, mas sugiro que elabore melhor a pergunta com o que você queria mostrasse e o que está a mostrar no momento

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int v1, v2;
    printf("Valor 1:");
    scanf("%d", &v1);
    printf("Valor 2:");
    scanf("%d", &v2);

    if(v1 == v2){
        printf("Os valores %d e %d são iguais.", v1, v2);
    }   
    else {
        printf("Os valores %d e %d são diferentes.", v1, v2);
        if(v1 > v2){
            printf("\nO maior valor é: %d e o menor é: %d.", v1, v2);
        }
        else{
            printf("\nO maior valor é: %d e o menor é: %d.", v2, v1);
        }
    }
}
```

Você só precisa saber se um valor é maior ou menor se eles forem diferentes, por isso usei uma [estrutura de decisão encadeada](http://linguagemc.com.br/estruturas-de-decisao-encadeadas-if-else-if-else/), ou seja, o programa só vai entrar no `if` ou no `else` caso os valores sejam diferentes.

Answer (score 5):

Você começou bem usando o `else` no primeiro `if`, deveria ter continuado assim. Então quando `v1` é maior que `v2` já tem motivo para escrever qual é o maior e qual é o menor ao mesmo tempo. E se não for, aí escreve o mesmo, mas dessa vez com as variáveis invertidas.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int v1, v2;
    printf("Valor 1 :"); scanf("%d", &v1);
    printf("Valor 2 :"); scanf("%d", &v2);
    if (v1 == v2) printf("O valor é igual\n");
    else printf("O valor é diferente\n");
    if (v1 > v2) printf("O valor maior é %d\nO valor menor é %d", v1, v2);
    else printf("O valor maior é %d\nO valor menor é %d", v2, v1);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/F2EcdD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/escwwman-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/IfElse.c).

Ou talvez quisesse nem ter dois `if`s, aí deveria usar um `if`, um `else if` e um `else`. Fica para fazê-lo, mas acho uma solução pior.

Comment: Obrigado, to começando na área.

Comment: @Gabriel veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado